# After updating android studio from 1.5 to 2.0 it give error saying restart.exe

Tags: android

After updating android studio from 1.5 to 2.0 it give error saying restart.exe doesnt found please help .I tired copying restarter.exe file form programefiles/android/bin and paste in user/home/android1.5/restart folder. But this is not working.it deletes restart.exe file while updating. Please HELP ﻿